# jpql select into select

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpql

it is possible to use one select's results as a table for another(in other word: upper) select statement. is there equivalent in jpql

Here is my sample sql statements

```
 SELECT X.NAME, SLS.TOTAL AS BENEFIT 
 (SELECT * FROM PERSON) X
 INNER JOIN SALESMAN SLS ON SLS.PERSON_ID = X.ID
```

what is the equivalant this statement in jpql?

Comment: Why do you need the nested `SELECT *` ? - it will kill performance. You can get the same result a lot more efficiently with `SELECT X.NAME, SLS.TOTAL AS BENEFIT
FROM PERSON X INNER JOIN SALESMAN SLS ON SLS.PERSON_ID = X.ID`

Comment: If you have not read it already, have a look at [http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.2.3/apache-openjpa/docs/jpa_langref.html#jpa_langref_subqueries]

Comment: SELECT X.NAME, SLS.TOTAL AS BENEFIT FROM PERSON 
INNER JOIN SALESMAN SLS ON SLS.PERSON_ID = PERSON.ID

it duplicates result so i use nested select

Comment: @PM77-1 is nested select possible for jpql?

Comment: According to the document I linked to, `sub-queries` are allowed only in `WHERE` and `HAVING` clauses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible. Subqueries can only be used in WHERE and HAVING clauses, as told in JPA 2.0 specification:

> Subqueries may be used in the WHERE or HAVING clause.[58]
>   ...
>   [58] Subqueries are restricted to the WHERE and HAVING clauses in this
>   release. Support for subqueries in the FROM clause will be considered
>   in a later release of this specification.

Also in JPA 2.1 this has not been changed.